# Arrays are null after passing them with Ajax to the next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Function:

```
$("#123").click(function(){
    var oberpunkte = new Array();
$('input:checkbox[class=oberpunkte]:checked').each(function() {
    oberpunkte.push($(this).attr('name'));

});

var unterpunkte = new Array();
$('input:checkbox[class=unterpunkte]:checked').each(function() {
unterpunkte.push($(this).attr('name'));

});

var kategorie = $("input:radio:checked[name='kategorie']").val();


$.ajax({
    TYPE: 'POST',
    url: 'selected.php',
    data: { oberpunkte:oberpunkte, unterpunkte: unterpunkte, kategorie: kategorie},
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#sumadd').html(data);
    }
     });

  });

});
```

php:

```
$oberp = $_POST['oberpunkte'];
$unterp = $_POST['unterpunkte'];
$katid = $_POST['kategorie'];

var_dump($oberp);
var_dump($unterp);
echo($katid);
```

I also alerted my Arrays before the `$.ajax` Method. They aren't null.

If I echo the passed Arrays I get the Value null.

I also searched Stackoverflow for similar questions and didn't find a solution which solved my problem.

I bet there is an easy mistake, I just can't figure it out.

MY Div where the output will be:

```
echo("<div id='sumadd'></div>");
```

The Output:

```
NULL NULL
```

Arrays:
Console.log ->
[image]

Comment: What does your array's look like (js) because you might need to encode them, serialize them or converted to json.

Comment: They are Strings. For Example { "Wordpress", "Typo3" }

Comment: can you add a sample of your html and output in a edit to your question

Comment: I added some more info.

Comment: castus found the mistake. I had to write "TYPE" in little letters like "type". I knew.. it was an easy mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object's methods are case sensitive try to change "TYPE" to "type" in $.ajax() method.

Answer (score -1):

Pass data to ajax as arrays:

```
data: { oberpunkte:[oberpunkte], unterpunkte: [unterpunkte], kategorie: [kategorie]},
```